# Writing to a text file with a variable for the name

Tags: c#, streamwriter

Alright, so my question is; I'm trying to save a file to the C: drive in a folder. Now, I know how to do this for regular files like

```
using(StreamWriter writer = new SteamWriter("c:\\Folder\\TextFile.txt");
```

What I've been trying to figure out is how I can make it so that the name of text file is the replaced with a variable so Its more like

```
using(StreamWriter writer = new SteamWriter("c:\\Folder\\Variablegoeshere.txt");
```

Is there anyway I can do this?

I apologize for my poor question asking skills.

Comment: why would people ever answer this kind of question...

Comment: Why wouldn't we, @zinking? A beginner has a question. Not that uncommon a question, really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `StreamWriter` constructor, like many other constructors and method calls, takes a string argument. You can pass it any string you like. In your first code sample, you're passing the constructor a "string literal" - an unnamed string variable with a constant value. Instead, you can pass a standard string variable, that you construct beforehand. For instance:

```
string name = // whatever you like
string path = "c:\\Folder\\" + name + ".txt"; // use '+' to combine strings
using (StreamWriter writer = new SteamWriter(path));
```

I usually like to use the [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) static method when I concatenate path components. Helps me avoid problems with missing or doubled backslashes:

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine("c:\\Folder", name + ".txt");
```

And, finally, with the [string verbatim modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx), you avoid those ugly double-backslashes, that are otherwise necessary because the backslash is the "escape" character in non-verbatim strings:

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"c:\Folder", name + ".txt");
```

Here's the [Microsoft developer reference page for strings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx). Worth a read, as is the larger [C# language reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/618ayhy6.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputPath = "c:\\Folder\\TextFile.txt";
var folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName( inputPath );
using ( var writer = new StreamWriter ( Path.Combine( folderPath, "Variablegoeshere.txt" ) )
```